# Cannot run CMake executable with or without debugger under Visual Studio 2017: "Access is denied."

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I'm attempting to run a program built with a CMake-generated solution file under Visual Studio 2017's debugger in order to debug a problem. However, whenever I try selecting `Start Debugging` or `Start Without Debugging` I get the following error popup.

> Unable to start program
>   'E:\build\someprogram\build\x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD
>
> Access is denied.

At first glance the problem sounded like the one described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49763/access-denied-when-attempting-to-run-under-the-deb.html). However, that bug was allegedly fixed in VS 2017 15.5, and I currently use 15.6.7. And the location of the compiled executable isn't on a RAM disk or network drive, but on a physical drive. And the error happens when running *without* a debugger also.

Also I wondered about whether or not the executable was not properly configured, since it looks like the error is related to the `ALL_BUILD` target, but in my `CMakeLists.txt` I have this declaration:

```
add_executable(someproject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I would think that would add the executable to run. It also appears as a subproject in the Solution Explorer.

The compiled `.exe` runs outside of Visual Studio fine, although it crashes, which I'm trying to debug. Strangely, I cannot enter the Visual Studio debugger from the `Abort/Retry/Ignore` dialogue that appears after the crash by clicking `Retry` like it instructs; the window for choosing the Visual Studio version never appears.

It does not seem to be a permissions issue since I manually adjusted the permission of all the build directories with all permissions, with no changes. I'm also running Visual Studio with administrator privileges, and it makes no difference. Additionally I replicated the build process on an entirely different machine (Windows 10, as opposed to Windows 7) and the exact same error occurs, so I'm suspecting it's a CMake issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a different project as startup project (right click on your target executable project `"someproject"` and select `"Set as StartUp Project"` from the context menu). `ALL_BUILD` is a symbolic target and is not connected to an executable.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like you can configure this inside CMake using something like this: `set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME})`